# In general, how do people obtain negative samples for cascade classifier training?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, cascade-classifier

If I want to implement a cascade classifier for detecting e.g. my jacket on an image, I can obtain the positive samples for it like this: take pictures of it from different angles and put each picture on a few backgrounds. If I want to detect any jacket (not only the mine one), I would need to take photos of ~500 (or more for a more precise classifier) different jackets.

But I'm not sure if there's a similar approach for negative samples. So, my question: is there a general approach (like the above one) to obtaining negative samples? Or do I have to craft one for each classifier?

**I'm not seeking recommendations for any specific books, tutorials, tools etc. I only want to know if there's a *generalized* approach for obtaining negative samples.**

Comment: opencv used to contain training of haar cascades. you pass it whole pictures with positive annotation ROIs. the training program then takes negatives from the remaining space.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz But in this official OpenCV [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html) it is stated that "the set of negative samples must be prepared manually".